Propagation of covariance matrix during a rotation
Suppose we have a rotation matrix representing an objects rotation in a certain frame $F_1$ along with a distribution of Euler Angles representing the probability that the object is perturbed from that frame. Suppose we want to change reference frames, how would we propagate the uncertainty to the new frame? Position offset would be straightforward but I'm unsure how to handle the rotation. After some thought I realized it's not as simple as applying a rotation matrix to the covariance.
